# Deprecated : contextual_help has been deprecated since version 3.3.0

Tags: wp-admin

I am getting below error in Admin Panel.

**Deprecated : contextual_help has been deprecated since version 3.3.0. Use get_current_screen () -> add_help_tab (), get_current_screen () -> remove_help_tab () instead. in /var/www/html/invertir/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5088**

[image]

I got below code in */var/www/html/invertir/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5088*

```
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_hook_trigger_error', true ) ) {
        $message = empty( $message ) ? '' : ' ' . $message;

        if ( ! is_null( $replacement ) ) {
            trigger_error(
                sprintf(
                    /* translators: 1: WordPress hook name, 2: Version number, 3: Alternative hook name. */
                    __( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.' ),
                    $hook,
                    $version,
                    $replacement
                ) . $message,
                E_USER_DEPRECATED
            );
        } else {
            trigger_error(
                sprintf(
                    /* translators: 1: WordPress hook name, 2: Version number. */
                    __( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.' ),
                    $hook,
                    $version
                ) . $message,
                E_USER_DEPRECATED
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I solve the issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to disable each plugin you have and each theme you have until you find which one is causing the issue. Then you can bring the issue up to the developers. The [Healthcheck & Troubleshooting Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) can help in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have a lot of updates, first, update everything, then you update the plugins, themes, then if that does not work then disable all your plugins and themes and see if that fixes the issue. If it does then you enable one plugin at a time until you have all your plugins enabled, if it appears again then you know that it is a plugin and you can remove your plugins, if it does not appear then you enable all your themes one at a time and do the same thing the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a plugin with `MailChimp` in the title.  I disabled all of these as I'm now using MailerLite, and the issue went away.

I hope this helps narrow down the offending plugin search for others.